# Aiogram calendar

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I need to create and change the standard callback to my own so that I can place two callback handlers in the project for two different calendars

```
async def get_calendar(callback: CallbackQuery, min_date: str, max_date: str):
    calendar = SimpleCalendar(locale=await get_user_locale(callback.from_user), show_alerts=True)
    calendar.set_dates_range(datetime.strptime(min_date, '%Y-%m-%d'),
                             datetime.strptime(max_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
    return calendar

@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'future')
async def future_func(callback: CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.delete()
    today = get_today()
    future_date = generate_date_future(today)
    await callback.message.answer('Choose date: ',
                                  reply_markup=await (await get_calendar(callback, today, future_date)).start_calendar()) # somewhere here, in theory, you need to change the callback


# set the prefix that the callback should have
@dp.callback_query(SimpleCalendarCallback(prefix='simple_calendar_period').filter())
async def process_simple_calendar(callback: CallbackQuery, callback_data: CallbackData, state: FSMContext):
    action = callback.data.split(':')[1]
    min_date, max_date = db.get_min_max_dates()
    calendar = await get_calendar(callback, min_date, max_date)
    selected, date = await calendar.process_selection(callback, callback_data)
    if selected and date:
        await callback.message.delete()
        date_list = [date.strftime('%Y'), date.strftime('%m'), date.strftime('%d')]
        period, str_date = db.get_current_period(date_list[0], date_list[1], date_list[2])
        period_str = msg_period(period)[0]
        all_notes = db.get_all_notes()
        await state.update_data(ccp_date='-'.join(date_list))
        await bot.send_message(admin_id,
                               period_str,
                               reply_markup=create_ikb(period_current_date_change_menu(all_notes)))
    elif action == 'CANCEL':
        await callback.message.delete()
        await bot.send_message(admin_id,
                               'Choose period:',
                               reply_markup=create_ikb(period_menu))
```

I don’t understand how to change the callback, I couldn’t find anything in the documentation
I will be glad to any answer